# On a system with fapolicyd enabled, how do I permit Java to run sqlitejdbc.so, which has a unique filename at each start?

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

My issue is fairly similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911385/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-sqlite-core-nativedb-open): I have a Java application running on Rhel 8 that relies on an sqlite-jdcb driver. Unlike in that issue, my issue isn't with my filesystem being mounted with noexec. Instead, its with fapolicyd prohibiting java from executing the driver:

```
Aug 02 11:36:40 hostname cerebro[3210818]: /opt/cerebro/sqlite-3.34.0-47390f7e-7dd5-45d7-9a01-0635f335df40-libsqlitejdbc.so (Operation not permitted)
Aug 02 11:36:42 hostname cerebro[3210818]: /opt/cerebro/sqlite-3.34.0-cb416389-64b7-4ed6-9e52-5c710ec85a6c-libsqlitejdbc.so (Operation not permitted)
```

Normally, I would use the [`fapolicyd-cli`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd_security-hardening) command to add the driver file to the fapolicyd trust list, but each time the application starts, the JDBC driver file has a unique filename, so adding an existing file isn't a viable option. Note the hexidecimal characters above - those are different at each application startup.

How do I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this based on the files mime type and path. Below is an example.

I create a file, `myfile`, and try to run it. I observe it's being blocked by fapolicyd:

```
[localuser@server ~]$ echo 'echo hello' > myfile-1
[localuser@server ~]$ chmod +x ./myfile-1
[localuser@server ~]$ ./myfile-1
bash: ./myfile-1: Operation not permitted
[localuser@server ~]$
```

You have two options to view a useful log output for `fapolicyd` debugging:

- one, `systemctl stop fapolicyd.service` and then run `fapolicyd-cli debug-deny` while waiting for a block
- two, modify any `deny` statements in `/etc/fapolicyd/rules.d/` to be `deny_log` or `deny_syslog`. To make this change take effect, `fapolicyd-cli --update; systemctl restart fapolicyd`

Once you are getting useful block statements, you should see a message like this:

`Aug  8 01:20:15 server.nix.turnerfarms.net fapolicyd[9083]: rule=16 dec=deny_log perm=execute auid=0 pid=9087 exe=/usr/bin/bash : path=/home/localuser/myfile-1 ftype=text/plain trust=0`

Above, we see that rule 16 blocked the file at `/home/localuser/myfile-1` from running. If we take a look at rule 16, we see it is this rule:

```
[root@server rules.d]# fapolicyd-cli --list | grep '^16
16. deny_log perm=execute all : all
```

The reason the rule number matters is that `fapolicyd` trust rules are processed lexically, meaning if we add a rule for an application it has to be in a file that comes before the one with the block in it.

Identify the file with the block:

```
[root@server rules.d]# grep -r 'deny_log perm=execute' /etc/fapolicyd/rules.d/
/etc/fapolicyd/rules.d/90-deny-execute.rules:deny_log perm=execute all : all
```

Since the name of `myfile-*` will always change, we can allow it based on mime type. If you look at the deny that was logged earlier, you will see that subject is `/usr/bin/bash` and the mimetype is `text/plain`

Create a new rule that precedes 90, let's say `89-allow-myfiles.rules`:

```
allow perm=execute exe=/usr/bin/bash : dir=/home/localuser/ ftype=text/plain
```

Notify `fapolicyd` of a policy update, and restart the service

```
fapolicyd-cli --update && systemctl restart fapolicyd
```

Replace SELinux contexts on our new files:

```
restorecon -Rv /etc/fapolicyd/rules.d/
```

And you should be good now:

```
[localuser@server ~]$ ./myfile-1
hello
[localuser@server ~]$ ./myfile-2
hello
```

You can customize the `subject` and `object` of the rule as much as you would like to improve security.

**TL;DR:** You can whitelist applications with a rule, which has a more advanced syntax than a trust. There are various configuration options, including mime type, uid, gid, and path. A simple way to do it is to find the mime type of your application and write a rule that whitelists that mime type in a given folder.

**References:**

- man 5 fapolicyd.rules
- Red Hat's [fapolicyd documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd_security-hardening#introduction-to-fapolicyd_assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd)

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but i'm not allowed to do those.

Following the instructions from @cutrightjm, I created the file /etc/fapolicyd/rules.d/01-sqlitejdbc.rules with the contents:

```
allow perm=open exe=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.352.b08-2.el8_7.x86_64/jre/bin/java : dir=/opt/cerebro/ ftype=application/x-sharedlib
```

Note this is very hard coded to the specific version of java on RHEL8.7.

It still feels ugly but it works.